# Jquery Add a checkbox to element if other box is checked and unhide id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkout page.  I have used Jquery to hide the credit card information box as 99% of the time it will not be used to run a card.  However if the credit card box is checked(#pmt-authorizenet_aim) I want to insert another checkbox and allow it to be checked by the user.  If it is then checked I want the credit card information box(.fec-credit-card-info) to be shown.  However when I use the below code to enter the checkbox with id #openCCField it shows the credit card information box at all times and no longer hides it by default.  Where am I going wrong?  This is what I have so far.

It can now be seen at http://www.sshorepizza.com/stackoverflow.html

```js
$(function() {
  $('#checkoutBillTo').hide();
  $('#add_tipLabel').hide();
  $('#add_tip').hide();
  $('.fec-credit-card-info').hide();
  $('input[id=pmt-authorizenet_aim]').val('cod');

});

$(function() {
  $('#pmt-authorizenet_aim').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('textarea[name="comments"]').val($('textarea[name="comments"]').val() + ' Credit Card ');
      $(this).append("<input type='checkbox' name='myCheckbox' id='openCCField' />");
    }
    if (('#openCCField').is(':checked')) {
      $('.fec-credit-card-info').show();
      $('input[id=pmt-authorizenet_aim]').val('cc');
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('#pmt-cod').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('textarea[name="comments"]').val($('textarea[name="comments"]').val() + ' Cash ');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bof payment -->
<div id="checkoutPaymentForm" class="split">
  <!-- <h1 id="checkoutPaymentHeading">Step 2 - Payment Information</h1> -->

  <fieldset class="fec-billing-methods fec-block-checkout fec-fieldset" id="checkoutPayment">
    <legend>Billing Details</legend>
    <span class="fec-fieldset-legend">Billing Details</span>

    <!--BILLING ADDRESS-->
    <fieldset id="checkoutBillTo" class="fec-shipping-address fec-shipping-to" style="display: none;">
      <legend>Billing Address</legend>
      <span class="fec-fieldset-legend-two">Billing Address</span>

      <div class="fec-address-container">
        <div id="checkoutBillto">
          <address>Carry Out Customer<br> 3026 East College Avenue<br> Ruskin, FL    33570<br> United States</address>
        </div>
        <a id="linkCheckoutPaymentAddr" href="https://onlineorder.sshorepizza.com/index.php?main_page=checkout_payment_address"><img src="includes/templates/template_default/buttons/english/button_change_address.gif" alt="Change Address" title=" Change Address " width="60" height="24"></a>
      </div>
    </fieldset>



    <strong>We accept:</strong> <img src="includes/templates/template_default/images/icons/cc1.gif" alt="" width="41" height="25"> <img src="includes/templates/template_default/images/icons/cc2.gif" alt="" width="50" height="30"> <img src="includes/templates/template_default/images/icons/cc3.gif"
      alt="" width="50" height="30"> <img src="includes/templates/template_default/images/icons/cc5.gif" alt="" width="50" height="30">

    <span class="fec-fieldset-legend-two">Billing info</span>

    <label class="inputLabel" for="add_tip" id="add_tipLabel" style="display: none;">Would you like to add a tip for the driver?</label>
    <input type="text" name="add_tip" size="5" id="add_tip" style="display: none;"><br class="clearBoth" id="add_tipBreak">


    <!-- <span class="fec-information">Please select a payment method for this order.</span> -->

    <div class="fec-box-check-radio">
      <input type="radio" name="payment" value="cod" id="pmt-authorizenet_aim">
    </div>

    <label for="pmt-authorizenet_aim" class="radioButtonLabel">Credit Card</label>



    <div class="fec-credit-card-info" style="display: none;">

      <div class="fec-field">
        <label for="authorizenet_aim-cc-owner" class="inputLabel">Cardholder Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="authorizenet_aim_cc_owner" value="Carry Out Customer" id="authorizenet_aim-cc-owner" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-authorizenet_aim')" autocomplete="off"> </div>

      <div class="fec-field">
        <label for="authorizenet_aim-cc-number" class="inputLabel">Credit Card Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="authorizenet_aim_cc_number" id="authorizenet_aim-cc-number" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-authorizenet_aim')" autocomplete="off"> </div>

      <div class="fec-field">
        <label for="authorizenet_aim-cc-expires-month" class="inputLabel">Expiry Date:</label>
        <select name="authorizenet_aim_cc_expires_month" id="authorizenet_aim-cc-expires-month" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-authorizenet_aim')">
          <option value="01">January - (01)</option>
          <option value="02">February - (02)</option>
          <option value="03" selected="selected">March - (03)</option>
          <option value="04">April - (04)</option>
          <option value="05">May - (05)</option>
          <option value="06">June - (06)</option>
          <option value="07">July - (07)</option>
          <option value="08">August - (08)</option>
          <option value="09">September - (09)</option>
          <option value="10">October - (10)</option>
          <option value="11">November - (11)</option>
          <option value="12">December - (12)</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;
        <select name="authorizenet_aim_cc_expires_year" id="authorizenet_aim-cc-expires-year" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-authorizenet_aim')">
          <option value="19">2019</option>
          <option value="20">2020</option>
          <option value="21">2021</option>
          <option value="22">2022</option>
          <option value="23">2023</option>
          <option value="24">2024</option>
          <option value="25">2025</option>
          <option value="26">2026</option>
          <option value="27">2027</option>
          <option value="28">2028</option>
          <option value="29">2029</option>
          <option value="30">2030</option>
          <option value="31">2031</option>
          <option value="32">2032</option>
          <option value="33">2033</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="fec-field">
        <label for="authorizenet_aim-cc-cvv" class="inputLabel">CVV Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="authorizenet_aim_cc_cvv" size="4" maxlength="4" id="authorizenet_aim-cc-cvv" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-authorizenet_aim')" autocomplete="off"> <a href="javascript:popupWindow('http://onlineorder.sshorepizza.com/index.php?main_page=popup_cvv_help')">What's this?</a>        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="fec-box-check-radio">
      <input type="radio" name="payment" value="cod" id="pmt-cod">
    </div>

    <label for="pmt-cod" class="radioButtonLabel">Cash</label>

    <div class="alert"></div>


    <!-- bof doublebox -->
    <!-- eof doublebox -->

  </fieldset>

  <!-- bof Gift Wrap -->
  <!-- eof Gift Wrap -->
</div>
<!-- eof payment -->

<!-- EOF PAYMENT -->

<!-- bog FEC v1.27 CHECKBOX -->
<!-- eof FEC v1.27 CHECKBOX -->
<!-- bof FEC v1.24a DROP DOWN -->
<!-- begin/comments -->

<fieldset class="fec-fieldset fec-block-checkout split" id="checkoutComments">
  <legend>Special Instructions / Order Comments</legend>
  <span class="fec-fieldset-legend">Special Instructions / Order Comments</span>

  <textarea name="comments" cols="45" rows="3"></textarea> </fieldset>
<!-- end/comments -->
```

Comment: Please click the `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: Are these in separate files? You only need one document ready wrapping your functions. If `.fec-credit-card-info` will rarely be shown you should be using `display: none;` in your css and only show it when needed.

Comment: No they are in the same file.  I am learning this.  I will try to combine them once I get this resolved.  Thank you for pointing out they can be in the same container.

Comment: `if (('#openCCField').is(':checked')) {`  typo on selector operation.

Comment: You cannot check `openCCField` is checked until it has been appended so you need to delegate . And you append it to a radio, not the parent of the radio

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please do so yourself in the future. As you can see on the error, you need to handle the openCCField correctly

Comment: Also update your jQuery to a newer version.

Comment: I am using jquery-1.10.2.min.js  I see that there are now 3.3.X versions.  Are they always backwards compatible or do I have to try and sort out if it will break functions written in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues

You cannot check openCCField is checked until it has been appended so you need to delegate or do as I did: insert it into the HTML and hide it

And you appended it to a radio, not the parent of the radio

Also the Credit card/ Cash text would be added over and over again

You really should update your jQuery too

```js
$(function() {
  $('#checkoutBillTo').hide();
  $('#add_tipLabel').hide();
  $('#add_tip').hide();
  $('.fec-credit-card-info').hide();
  $('input[id=pmt-authorizenet_aim]').val('cod');

});

$(function() {

  $('#pmt-authorizenet_aim').on("click",function() {
    var text = $('textarea[name="comments"]').val(),
       check = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('#openCCField').toggle(check);
    $('textarea[name="comments"]').val(text.replace(" Cash ","")+ " Credit card ")
  })
  $('#openCCField').on("click",function() {
    var check = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('.fec-credit-card-info').toggle(check);
    $('input[id=pmt-authorizenet_aim]').val(check?'cc':"");
  });
  $('#pmt-cod').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var text = $('textarea[name="comments"]').val()
      $('textarea[name="comments"]').val(text.replace(" Credit card ","")+ " Cash ")
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#openCCField { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bof payment -->
<div id="checkoutPaymentForm" class="split">
  <!-- <h1 id="checkoutPaymentHeading">Step 2 - Payment Information</h1> -->

  <fieldset class="fec-billing-methods fec-block-checkout fec-fieldset" id="checkoutPayment">
    <legend>Billing Details</legend>
    <span class="fec-fieldset-legend">Billing Details</span>

    <!--BILLING ADDRESS-->
    <fieldset id="checkoutBillTo" class="fec-shipping-address fec-shipping-to" style="display: none;">
      <legend>Billing Address</legend>
      <span class="fec-fieldset-legend-two">Billing Address</span>

      <div class="fec-address-container">
        <div id="checkoutBillto">
          <address>Carry Out Customer<br> 3026 East College Avenue<br> Ruskin, FL    33570<br> United States</address>
        </div>
        <a id="linkCheckoutPaymentAddr" href="https://onlineorder.sshorepizza.com/index.php?main_page=checkout_payment_address"><img src="includes/templates/template_default/buttons/english/button_change_address.gif" alt="Change Address" title=" Change Address " width="60" height="24"></a>
      </div>
    </fieldset>



    <strong>We accept:</strong> <img src="includes/templates/template_default/images/icons/cc1.gif" alt="" width="41" height="25"> <img src="includes/templates/template_default/images/icons/cc2.gif" alt="" width="50" height="30"> <img src="includes/templates/template_default/images/icons/cc3.gif"
      alt="" width="50" height="30"> <img src="includes/templates/template_default/images/icons/cc5.gif" alt="" width="50" height="30">

    <span class="fec-fieldset-legend-two">Billing info</span>

    <label class="inputLabel" for="add_tip" id="add_tipLabel" style="display: none;">Would you like to add a tip for the driver?</label>
    <input type="text" name="add_tip" size="5" id="add_tip" style="display: none;"><br class="clearBoth" id="add_tipBreak">


    <!-- <span class="fec-information">Please select a payment method for this order.</span> -->

    <div class="fec-box-check-radio">
      <input type="radio" name="payment" value="cod" id="pmt-authorizenet_aim">
      <input type='checkbox' name='myCheckbox' id='openCCField' />
    </div>

    <label for="pmt-authorizenet_aim" class="radioButtonLabel">Credit Card</label>



    <div class="fec-credit-card-info" style="display: none;">

      <div class="fec-field">
        <label for="authorizenet_aim-cc-owner" class="inputLabel">Cardholder Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="authorizenet_aim_cc_owner" value="Carry Out Customer" id="authorizenet_aim-cc-owner" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-authorizenet_aim')" autocomplete="off"> </div>

      <div class="fec-field">
        <label for="authorizenet_aim-cc-number" class="inputLabel">Credit Card Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="authorizenet_aim_cc_number" id="authorizenet_aim-cc-number" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-authorizenet_aim')" autocomplete="off"> </div>

      <div class="fec-field">
        <label for="authorizenet_aim-cc-expires-month" class="inputLabel">Expiry Date:</label>
        <select name="authorizenet_aim_cc_expires_month" id="authorizenet_aim-cc-expires-month" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-authorizenet_aim')">
          <option value="01">January - (01)</option>
          <option value="02">February - (02)</option>
          <option value="03" selected="selected">March - (03)</option>
          <option value="04">April - (04)</option>
          <option value="05">May - (05)</option>
          <option value="06">June - (06)</option>
          <option value="07">July - (07)</option>
          <option value="08">August - (08)</option>
          <option value="09">September - (09)</option>
          <option value="10">October - (10)</option>
          <option value="11">November - (11)</option>
          <option value="12">December - (12)</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;
        <select name="authorizenet_aim_cc_expires_year" id="authorizenet_aim-cc-expires-year" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-authorizenet_aim')">
          <option value="19">2019</option>
          <option value="20">2020</option>
          <option value="21">2021</option>
          <option value="22">2022</option>
          <option value="23">2023</option>
          <option value="24">2024</option>
          <option value="25">2025</option>
          <option value="26">2026</option>
          <option value="27">2027</option>
          <option value="28">2028</option>
          <option value="29">2029</option>
          <option value="30">2030</option>
          <option value="31">2031</option>
          <option value="32">2032</option>
          <option value="33">2033</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="fec-field">
        <label for="authorizenet_aim-cc-cvv" class="inputLabel">CVV Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="authorizenet_aim_cc_cvv" size="4" maxlength="4" id="authorizenet_aim-cc-cvv" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-authorizenet_aim')" autocomplete="off"> <a href="javascript:popupWindow('http://onlineorder.sshorepizza.com/index.php?main_page=popup_cvv_help')">What's this?</a>        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="fec-box-check-radio">
      <input type="radio" name="payment" value="cod" id="pmt-cod">
    </div>

    <label for="pmt-cod" class="radioButtonLabel">Cash</label>

    <div class="alert"></div>


    <!-- bof doublebox -->
    <!-- eof doublebox -->

  </fieldset>

  <!-- bof Gift Wrap -->
  <!-- eof Gift Wrap -->
</div>
<!-- eof payment -->

<!-- EOF PAYMENT -->

<!-- bog FEC v1.27 CHECKBOX -->
<!-- eof FEC v1.27 CHECKBOX -->
<!-- bof FEC v1.24a DROP DOWN -->
<!-- begin/comments -->

<fieldset class="fec-fieldset fec-block-checkout split" id="checkoutComments">
  <legend>Special Instructions / Order Comments</legend>
  <span class="fec-fieldset-legend">Special Instructions / Order Comments</span>

  <textarea name="comments" cols="45" rows="3"></textarea> </fieldset>
<!-- end/comments -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting completely over on my answer since I now have the HTML and an example. Still not sure exactly what you are expecting to happen, but what you're asking for is working in this code.

**JS**

> One issue with your code, was that you were trying to append the radio
>   button rather than it's container. I elected to use `after` instead.
>   The second issue was that you needed a separate event listener for the
>   checkbox when it's created. That event listener also needed event
>   delegation since it's a dynamically created element that doesn't exist
>   when DOM is loaded.
>
> I suppose you will also need an event for the cash radio so it can remove the checkbox for the credit card.

**CSS**

> I removed your inline styles and moved them to separate CSS, better to
>   stay away from them if you can.

```js
$('input[id=pmt-authorizenet_aim]').val('cod');

$('#pmt-authorizenet_aim').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('textarea[name="comments"]').val($('textarea[name="comments"]').val() + ' Credit Card ');
    // only create checkbox if it does not already exist
    if (!$('#openCCField').length) {
     $(this).after("<input type='checkbox' name='myCheckbox' id='openCCField' />");
    }
  }
});

$('#pmt-cod').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('textarea[name="comments"]').val($('textarea[name="comments"]').val() + ' Cash ');
  }
});

$('#checkoutPaymentForm').on('click', '#openCCField', function() {
  // using toggle allows you to show/hide automatically
  $('.fec-credit-card-info').toggle();
  $('input[id=pmt-authorizenet_aim]').val('cc');
});
```

```css
.fec-credit-card-info,
#checkoutBillTo,
#add_tipLabel,
#add_tip {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkoutPaymentForm" class="split">
  <!-- <h1 id="checkoutPaymentHeading">Step 2 - Payment Information</h1> -->

  <fieldset class="fec-billing-methods fec-block-checkout fec-fieldset" id="checkoutPayment">
    <legend>Billing Details</legend>

    <!--BILLING ADDRESS-->
    <fieldset id="checkoutBillTo" class="fec-shipping-address fec-shipping-to">
      <legend>Billing Address</legend>
      <span class="fec-fieldset-legend-two">Billing Address</span>

      <div class="fec-address-container">
        <div id="checkoutBillto">
          <address>Carry Out Customer<br> 3026 East College Avenue<br> Ruskin, FL    33570<br> United States</address>
        </div>
        <a id="linkCheckoutPaymentAddr" href="https://onlineorder.sshorepizza.com/index.php?main_page=checkout_payment_address"><img src="includes/templates/template_default/buttons/english/button_change_address.gif" alt="Change Address" title=" Change Address " width="60" height="24"></a>
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <strong>We accept:</strong> <img src="includes/templates/template_default/images/icons/cc1.gif" alt="" width="41" height="25"> <img src="includes/templates/template_default/images/icons/cc2.gif" alt="" width="50" height="30"> <img src="includes/templates/template_default/images/icons/cc3.gif"
      alt="" width="50" height="30"> <img src="includes/templates/template_default/images/icons/cc5.gif" alt="" width="50" height="30">

    <div class="fec-fieldset-legend-two">Billing info</div>

    <label class="inputLabel" for="add_tip" id="add_tipLabel" style="display: none;">Would you like to add a tip for the driver?</label>
    <input type="text" name="add_tip" size="5" id="add_tip" style="display: none;"><br class="clearBoth" id="add_tipBreak">


    <!-- <span class="fec-information">Please select a payment method for this order.</span> -->

    <label for="pmt-authorizenet_aim" class="radioButtonLabel">Credit Card</label>
    <div class="fec-box-check-radio">
      <input type="radio" name="payment" value="cod" id="pmt-authorizenet_aim">
    </div>

    <div class="fec-credit-card-info">

      <div class="fec-field">
        <label for="authorizenet_aim-cc-owner" class="inputLabel">Cardholder Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="authorizenet_aim_cc_owner" value="Carry Out Customer" id="authorizenet_aim-cc-owner" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-authorizenet_aim')" autocomplete="off"> </div>

      <div class="fec-field">
        <label for="authorizenet_aim-cc-number" class="inputLabel">Credit Card Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="authorizenet_aim_cc_number" id="authorizenet_aim-cc-number" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-authorizenet_aim')" autocomplete="off"> </div>

      <div class="fec-field">
        <label for="authorizenet_aim-cc-expires-month" class="inputLabel">Expiry Date:</label>
        <select name="authorizenet_aim_cc_expires_month" id="authorizenet_aim-cc-expires-month" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-authorizenet_aim')">
          <option value="01">January - (01)</option>
          <option value="02">February - (02)</option>
          <option value="03" selected="selected">March - (03)</option>
          <option value="04">April - (04)</option>
          <option value="05">May - (05)</option>
          <option value="06">June - (06)</option>
          <option value="07">July - (07)</option>
          <option value="08">August - (08)</option>
          <option value="09">September - (09)</option>
          <option value="10">October - (10)</option>
          <option value="11">November - (11)</option>
          <option value="12">December - (12)</option>
        </select> &nbsp;
        <select name="authorizenet_aim_cc_expires_year" id="authorizenet_aim-cc-expires-year" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-authorizenet_aim')">
          <option value="19">2019</option>
          <option value="20">2020</option>
          <option value="21">2021</option>
          <option value="22">2022</option>
          <option value="23">2023</option>
          <option value="24">2024</option>
          <option value="25">2025</option>
          <option value="26">2026</option>
          <option value="27">2027</option>
          <option value="28">2028</option>
          <option value="29">2029</option>
          <option value="30">2030</option>
          <option value="31">2031</option>
          <option value="32">2032</option>
          <option value="33">2033</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="fec-field">
        <label for="authorizenet_aim-cc-cvv" class="inputLabel">CVV Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="authorizenet_aim_cc_cvv" size="4" maxlength="4" id="authorizenet_aim-cc-cvv" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-authorizenet_aim')" autocomplete="off"> <a href="javascript:popupWindow('http://onlineorder.sshorepizza.com/index.php?main_page=popup_cvv_help')">What's this?</a>        </div>


    </div>
    <label for="pmt-cod" class="radioButtonLabel">Cash</label>
    <div class="fec-box-check-radio">
      <input type="radio" name="payment" value="cod" id="pmt-cod">
    </div>

    <div class="alert"></div>


    <!-- bof doublebox -->
    <!-- eof doublebox -->

  </fieldset>

  <!-- bof Gift Wrap -->
  <!-- eof Gift Wrap -->
</div>
<!-- eof payment -->

<!-- EOF PAYMENT -->

<!-- bog FEC v1.27 CHECKBOX -->
<!-- eof FEC v1.27 CHECKBOX -->
<!-- bof FEC v1.24a DROP DOWN -->
<!-- begin/comments -->

<fieldset class="fec-fieldset fec-block-checkout split" id="checkoutComments">
<legend>Special Instructions / Order Comments</legend>

<textarea name="comments" cols="45" rows="3"></textarea> </fieldset>
```

Comment: This isn't working. I will work on getting a mock up of the page.  I cannot link to it as it is at the end of a shopping cart on an internal store site.